# Why is the signal sawtooth shaped?

Tags: atmega, timer, atmel, isr

I am currently working with interfacing a stepper motor (4-pin bipolar), and providing it the propper input signal, such that it accelelrate and decellerate correctly. 
In recently also across an [application note](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8017.pdf) by atmel (link), which adresses this issue, and also provides the code for programming a timer to do so which is available on [github](https://github.com/plastiv/stepper-motor-controller/blob/master/%20stepper-motor-controller%20--username%20plastiv%40gmail.com/code/speed_cntr.c) (github).. (Perfect)
Since i already have the driver, i don't need to provide it a 4 pin signal (A+,A-,B-,B+) but only a pulse modulated signal, with a increasing and decreasing the frequency for a given amount of steps.

I changed the ISR routine, as it seemed to be where the step signal seemed to be generated, and changed it to toggle the state of the step_pin everytime an interrupt occured, thus recreating a PWM signal. Problem is though that signal doesn't resemble that, and if i remove the `Serial.print()` become the signal a sawtooth shaped signal.

[image]    ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
    {
      // Holds next delay period.
      unsigned int new_step_delay;

```
  // Remember the last step delay used when accelrating.
  static int last_accel_delay;

  // Counting steps when moving.
  static unsigned int step_count = 0;

  // Keep track of remainder from new_step-delay calculation to incrase accurancy
  static unsigned int rest = 0;

  OCR1A = profile.step_delay;
  Serial.print('\n');
  Serial.print("step_delay: ");
  Serial.println(profile.step_delay);
  Serial.print('\n');

  switch (profile.run_state)
  {

    case STOP:
      step_count = 0;
      rest = 0;
      TCCR1B &= ~((1 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10)); // Stop the timer,  No clock source
      break;

    case ACCEL:
      digitalWrite(step_pin,!digitalRead(step_pin));
      //delay(1);
      //digitalWrite(step_pin,LOW);
      step_count++;
      profile.accel_count++;
      new_step_delay = profile.step_delay - (((2 * (long)profile.step_delay) + rest) / (4 * profile.accel_count + 1));
      rest = ((2 * (long)profile.step_delay) + rest) % (4 * profile.accel_count + 1);

      // Chech if we should start decelration.
      if (step_count >= profile.decel_start)
      {
        profile.accel_count = profile.decel_val;
        profile.run_state = DECEL;
      }

      // Chech if we hitted max speed.
      else if (new_step_delay <= profile.min_time_delay)
      {
        last_accel_delay = new_step_delay;
        new_step_delay = profile.min_time_delay;
        rest = 0;
        profile.run_state = RUN;
      }
      break;
    case RUN:
       digitalWrite(step_pin,!digitalRead(step_pin));
      //delay(1);
      //digitalWrite(step_pin,LOW);
      step_count++;
      new_step_delay = profile.min_time_delay;
      // Chech if we should start decelration.
      if (step_count >= profile.decel_start) 
      {
        profile.accel_count = profile.decel_val;
        // Start decelration with same delay as accel ended with.
        new_step_delay = last_accel_delay;
        profile.run_state = DECEL;
      }
      break;
    case DECEL:
      digitalWrite(step_pin,!digitalRead(step_pin));
      step_count++;
      profile.accel_count++;
      new_step_delay = profile.step_delay - (((2 * (long)profile.step_delay) + rest)/(4 * profile.accel_count + 1));
      rest = ((2 * (long)profile.step_delay)+rest)%(4 * profile.accel_count + 1);
      // Check if we at last step
      if(profile.accel_count >= 0)
      {
        profile.run_state = STOP;
      }
      break;

  }
    profile.step_delay = new_step_delay;
}
```

The ISR routine is here..

```
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  // Holds next delay period.
  unsigned int new_step_delay;

  // Remember the last step delay used when accelrating.
  static int last_accel_delay;

  // Counting steps when moving.
  static unsigned int step_count = 0;

  // Keep track of remainder from new_step-delay calculation to incrase accurancy
  static unsigned int rest = 0;

  OCR1A = profile.step_delay;
  Serial.print('\n');
  Serial.print("step_delay: ");
  Serial.println(profile.step_delay);
  Serial.print('\n');

  switch (profile.run_state)
  {

    case STOP:
      step_count = 0;
      rest = 0;
      TCCR1B &= ~((1 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10)); // Stop the timer,  No clock source
      break;

    case ACCEL:
      digitalWrite(step_pin,!digitalRead(step_pin));
      //delay(1);
      //digitalWrite(step_pin,LOW);
      step_count++;
      profile.accel_count++;
      new_step_delay = profile.step_delay - (((2 * (long)profile.step_delay) + rest) / (4 * profile.accel_count + 1));
      rest = ((2 * (long)profile.step_delay) + rest) % (4 * profile.accel_count + 1);

      // Chech if we should start decelration.
      if (step_count >= profile.decel_start)
      {
        profile.accel_count = profile.decel_val;
        profile.run_state = DECEL;
      }

      // Chech if we hitted max speed.
      else if (new_step_delay <= profile.min_time_delay)
      {
        last_accel_delay = new_step_delay;
        new_step_delay = profile.min_time_delay;
        rest = 0;
        profile.run_state = RUN;
      }
      break;
    case RUN:
       digitalWrite(step_pin,!digitalRead(step_pin));
      //delay(1);
      //digitalWrite(step_pin,LOW);
      step_count++;
      new_step_delay = profile.min_time_delay;
      // Chech if we should start decelration.
      if (step_count >= profile.decel_start) 
      {
        profile.accel_count = profile.decel_val;
        // Start decelration with same delay as accel ended with.
        new_step_delay = last_accel_delay;
        profile.run_state = DECEL;
      }
      break;
    case DECEL:
      digitalWrite(step_pin,!digitalRead(step_pin));
      step_count++;
      profile.accel_count++;
      new_step_delay = profile.step_delay - (((2 * (long)profile.step_delay) + rest)/(4 * profile.accel_count + 1));
      rest = ((2 * (long)profile.step_delay)+rest)%(4 * profile.accel_count + 1);
      // Check if we at last step
      if(profile.accel_count >= 0)
      {
        profile.run_state = STOP;
      }
      break;

  }
    profile.step_delay = new_step_delay;
}
```

main

```
#include "speed_profile.h"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  cli();
  Serial.begin(230400);
  output_pin_setup();
  timer1_setup();
  sei();
}

void loop() 
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.print("start");
  Serial.print('\n');

  int motor_steps = 10000;
  // Accelration to use.
  int motor_acceleration = 10;
  // Deceleration to use.
  int motor_deceleration = 10;
  // Speed to use.
  int motor_speed = 500;
  compute_speed_profile(motor_steps, motor_acceleration, motor_deceleration, motor_speed);
  Serial.print("NewRound");
  Serial.print('\n');

}
```

output_pin_setup();

```
void output_pin_setup()
{
  pinMode(en_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dir_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(step_pin,OUTPUT); 
}
```

The rest if the code is the same as before, and available on github.

I know i am doing something wrong here? but how do i create the desired signal?

here is the schematic of the setup:

[image: Setup]

**Edit - Setup output_pins()**
I use the function setup_output_pins()
To setup the output pins, i did though read somewhere that wasn't a good idea as the arduino need some time to settle or something?

Comment: ... and your schematic is where?

Comment: A schmatic of how things are connected has been added.. I pretty sure the error is in the code, and not in the setup..

Comment: well... At the moment i just testing it, So the arduino uno and the motor driver board ST330 aren't connected. 
I am currently scoping the output of the arduino

Comment: You have to load the GPIO, leaving the GPIO floating makes sense such output transition.

Comment: I think that might have been it, it seem to create a fine square wave now..  

now I only need to hook it up and see if it actually works.

Comment: @Sorrow When you'll finish, you can answer your own question, with new scope image. Maybe you will help someone with similar problem.

Comment: Well the stepper motor moves, but i think something is wrong with the math. It change doesn't speed is being which the PWM does shows as well, as the PWM frequency stays nearly constant. around 521 Hz what ever speed tell it to go to.

Comment: Or whatever acceleration I want it to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question was regarding why i am getting a sawtooth signal rather than a square signal, will this answer "close" this question.

@Marko Buršič mentioned that the issue might have been that the Pins were floating, seemed to have been the case. initiliazing them in the setup routine fixed the issue I had and provided me with the desired square shaped signal.

[image: Blurred image of the wanted signal]